# In node js project, how to write a command which runs on linux command line

Tags: node.js, linux, command-line

I am working on a node js project and in this project I need to write a command that will run on the linux command line. The command is

> ssh -L 0.0.0.0:9999:hostname:5905 username@hostname

I have tried the cmd.run() function and it is running the command but as this is a ssh command it is asking for a password and the project is struck on that.

Someone please help me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If wanted to do `ssh` without it asking for password, you may do key exchanges (copying yours public key to target host), so it will authenticate you with the key directly.

Regarding using `ssh` for nodejs program, would suggest use a nodejs wrapper library of ssh for it, as it already handles many edge cases of interacting with the commandline.

One of the wrapper libraries you may take a look at is [node-ssh](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ssh), there is already some examples that you can refer to and try out.

Comment: thank you for your quick reply. I read the node-ssh that you have suggested.

I have done

> cmd.run('ssh -L 0.0.0.0:9999:hostname:5905 username@hostname');

Then trying to do this.
> cmd.run(password);
this password variable contains the password of the host.
But it is not taking the password.
May you please suggest how to do this.

Comment: @NitinBishnoi you may refer to [this guide](https://geekflare.com/linux-ssh-key-exchange/) for doing the key exchange.

TLDR: generate a rsa key and also place the public key to target host's .ssh/authorized_keys file

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
this solution work if the project is running on one server and limited clients get to use it.
but what if this project needed to run on multiple different server at different places and number of clients is high.
Will this work for all of them?